# EFI (Legacy) BIOS Doesn't Detect SATA-Based NVME M.2 SSD

Tags: windows-10, boot, ssd, bios, m.2

So, I'm a terrible planner. I'm a high-level software engineer, so obviously I think hardware is just pure magic. So I go out and buy a Seagate Barracude 510 NVME SSD & a M.2 -> PCIe x4 adapter. Plug the SSD into the adapter, pluck it in, & bingo bango; Windows recognizes all 960 gbs.

However, there's a catch. Windows seems to be operating at full force with it's  `Standard NVM Express Controller` that seems to help it recognise the bastard. Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to be affecting the EFI legacy BIOS (i have no UEFI option on my 8 ?? year old amalgamation)

Sooo... is there any way of booting from the drive, or atleast getting the EFI bios to recognize it? Windows CAN transfer data back and forth, so I know it works.

-- begin edit 1 --

[Motherboard Information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ycwfD.png)

Comment: Nope, NVMe is a hardware implementation. If the motherboard is older than 2015 then nope. Only the Z97 and later have NVMe support.

Comment: Don't die...you still should have access to the drive and be able to use a good part of it's speed as secondary storage.

Answer (score 2):

## You'd need to mod your BIOS

Platforms prior to [Z97/X99 don't support PCI-e based booting](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005967/memory-and-storage/enthusiast-ssds.html); although you can see and use the drive by default, you cannot boot from it. That said, it is possible to modify older BIOSs to support it by adding a the EFI module along [these lines](https://www.win-raid.com/t871f50-Guide-How-to-get-full-NVMe-support-for-all-Systems-with-an-AMI-UEFI-BIOS-7.html#msg17072). If you're comfortable installing someone else's binaries, you can find a modded BIOS [here](https://rog.asus.com/forum/showthread.php?48001-R4E-BIOS-4804-MODDED-EFI-Intel-13-1-0-2126-Download/page46#post677303).

Comment: Is the Maximus platform compatible with the Rampage platform? Come to think of it, they both seem to sound like nicknames for US marines so surely they have to be alike in some way?

Comment: @superscript -  They have nothing in common.  One is an Intel motherboard the other is an AMD motherboard.

Comment: this is why I don't work with hardware.. thanks so much

Comment: @Ramhound Scroll down to post 454, there’s a link for the Maximus IV Extreme Z. Also, Rampage is for Intel’s HEDT platform (here X79), not AMD, which would be Crosshair. I’ll update the link in the post to link directly to that one.

Comment: Nice find. Please note that it may create other issues. If you're not confident messing with BIOS updates, leave this to a pro. If it breaks, they're the one that'll pay. xD

Comment: @NatsuKage Absolutely, if you’re not comfortable, don’t do it! At least this is somewhat safer since it’s adding a new extension rather than modifying existing ones.

Answer (score 2):

The Solution is here! After millennia of slaving away at my linux-bound PC, I have all of the tools for users who come across this post.

For the solution, you're gonna have to use a USB drive, so go get one for $10 if you don't have one already.

1. Ensure that your USB Drive is formatted as Fat32, a format tool for 64gb+ drives can be found [here](https://dlcdnimgs.asus.com/websites/global/products/9JB5jBpArfvcpcNi/UBF.jpg)
2. Get the ROM that fits your specific motherboard [here](https://onedrive.live.com/?authkey=%21AHeT82KI488djfU&id=8958E7AE29E4BA6C%2110181&cid=8958E7AE29E4BA6C) (Older Motherboards can be found in the `/NVME TESTING` directory.
3. Insert the USB drive into the ASUS Flashback port (located on the back, [usually highlighted in white, below or next to the flashback button](https://dlcdnimgs.asus.com/websites/global/products/9JB5jBpArfvcpcNi/UBF.jpg))
4. **WITH THE COMPUTER OFF** (But on *standby* power) press and hold the Flashback button for ~3s until it starts flashing
5. Remove the USB Drive when the light is done flashing. You're done with the first half!
6. Download your OS, flashing it with [RUFUS](https://rufus.ie/) onto the same drive you used for flashback (for economic purposes)
7. Boot from the USB Drive
8. ???
9. Profit!